# Kotlin Map using Operators

Tags: kotlin, sortedmap

Started playing the weekend with Kotlin and trying to get maps working with operators.  Somehow Kotlin tells me I am confusing it with ambiguity.

Here is code that works (syntactically not like I want it to):

```
var columns = sortedMapOf("a" to 1, "b" to 2)
columns.plusAssign("c" to 3)
```

And here is code that simply does not compile (but syntactically closer to what I want)

```
var cs = sortedMapOf(1 to "a", 2 to "b")
cs += Pair(3, "c")
```

What shorthand operator magic/casting am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I understand the question, but I would just resolve it with `columns.put("c", 3);`

Comment: JB, agreed - there is a 100 ways to make it work (functionally).  The point is that Kotlin supports the += operator and that it should work, and I want to use it as it reads mathematically I want my code to read.  Also, by me not getting it to work means that I am conceptually missing something

Comment: I relayed your question on the kotlin slack channel. Let's see if an answer comes up...

Comment: JB - in follow up to your answer of columns.put...  even more natural would be `code` cs[4] = "f"

Comment: `cs[4] = "c"` also won't allocate an aditional object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ambiguity here is because Kotlin can interpret the expression `cs += Pair(3, "c")` either as operation creating new map from the original map and the given pair and assigning that map back to variable `cs = cs.plus(Pair(3, "c"))`, or as operation mutating the original map `cs.plusAssign(Pair(3, "c"))`

To disambiguate this situation, follow the Kotlin motto — make `val`, not `var`!

When you declare `cs` as val (non-mutable variable), it cannot be reassigned once it has been initialized, so the only operation becomes available here is `plusAssign`.

Comment: Can you confirm that there's no way to resolve the ambiguity if cs is a var and not a val?

Comment: Ilya - thanks - confirmed and working.  Wow!  Don't quite know what to make of it (definitely is a change of pattern for everything I was used to in pretty much every other language)...  but will look out for it now.  The other thing is that why can it figure out cs.plusAssign() but not cs.+= with the same Pair parameter.  I would naturally have thought that it knew what was coming and where it was going.

Comment: Sorry - the second question you answered already... was just thinking out loud.

Comment: Also note that technically there is no problem for a compiler to resolve this issue automatically. But Kotlin reports ambiguity on purpose,  just to ease the life of a human reader.